# Google API get reviews for my business using java script

Tags: javascript, angular, google-api, google-oauth, google-developers-console

I am trying to get google reviews for my business but struggling with implementing it. Can someone share how to get the latest/top 5 reviews using google business API using JavaScript/Postman? I was trying to do so:

GET:

> https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=MY_CLIENT_SECRET&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage&response_type=token&redirect_uri=https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground

but it doesn't work.

Was trying also testing it on [Google oauth playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/)

filling:OAuth flow: Client-side
Use your own OAuth credentials: my Client ID here

Step 1:

Authorize API: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.business.manage
but here I am getting:

> Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
> The redirect URI in the request, https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. To update the authorized redirect URIs, visit: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/938304287177-nkvm5mqk3f5uq9lt9j2srqlgd0bjihip.apps.googleusercontent.com?project=938304287177

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The redirect uri in your project on Google cloud console must exactly match the redirect uri you are sending from The easiest solution is to go to your project and add it.

```
https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground
```

Which is not the same as as you have an extra slash on the end

```
https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/
```

This video will walk you though it. [Google OAuth2: How the fix redirect_uri_mismatch error.](https://youtu.be/QHz1Rs6lZHQ)

## Question from Comments

> how can I get the reviews using just API key without a need to authorize it using gmail account?

If you check the documentation [Method: accounts.locations.reviews.list](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations.reviews/list) you will find that it says the following

[image]

API keys only allow you to access public data,  the data you are trying to access is private user data and therefore requires authorization in order to access it.  You can not use an API key to access this data you must be authorized using one of the above scopes.  A video which explains api keys. [Everything you need to know about Google API Key's, and where to get one.](https://youtu.be/kUB2qBo2aS4)

Comment: thanks for the response, but how can I get the reviews using just API key without a need to authorize it using gmail account? I just want to display reviews on my e-commerce shop

Comment: Check my update you cant this is private user data you need to be authorized.

Comment: ok, thx. sorry but how to make it authorized? I cannot ask any user of my page to authorize in order to display reviews I was given? Am I missing something?

Comment: I think that what you want to do is not possible with Javascript.  If you were using a server sided language you could request a refresh token and then use that to display it again to the users.  Really i would do this as a service run it once a night and grab  your data and store it in the database you shouldnt need to request this data live.